# LaTeX: Cannot add caption to longtblr

Tags: latex

I am trying to add a table caption / title to my table but the normal "\caption{title}" option does not work, and I could not find alternatives online. Does anybody know how can I add a table but keeping the longtblr option?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, justification=justified, singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{changepage}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{url}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt plus 0.3ex}
\renewcommand\refname{References}
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}


\begin{landscape}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
  \label{oa_tab:quotes}
  \centering 
    \begin{longtblr}{
      colspec={X[l,0.5]X[l,0.5]X[c,1.5]X[l,0.5]X[l,2]}
    }
    \hline\hline
    \textbf{Party} & \textbf{Person} & \textbf{Employment} & \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Quote}  \\ \cline{1-5} 
A & John  & Works & May 2022 & "Some random text"                                            \\ \hline
B & Sam & Works & May 2021  & "Some random text" \\                 
    \hline \hline
  \end{longtblr}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The caption is set in optional settings `[caption={...}]`, e.g. `\begin{longtblr}[caption={The caption}]{colspec={...}} ... \end{longtblr}`